# ASP.NET Webサイトの画面表示のパフォーマンス改善をしたい

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

塾の評価システムの開発を行っています。
ASP.NET MVC（vb.NET、 .NET Framework4.6）で構築したWebアプリケーションです。

縦に生徒の名称、横に評価項目がある一覧表をHTMLで生成しており、
各セルがテキストボックスで点数(0~100)を入力出来る様になっています。
（セルごとに点数入力後、DBへのデータ更新あり）

その一覧表の数が膨大で、500行 * 40列程度の一覧となり、入力項目が合計で2万セルほど存在します。
項目数が多いのがネックで画面の初期表示に30秒ほど時間が掛かっており、パフォーマンスに問題がある状態です。
サーバ、クライアントの通信量、通信回数の削減の為、静的ファイル(JS、CSS)のバンドル、サーバレスポンスのgzip圧縮などの対応は実施致しましたが、芳しくない状態です。

以下の観点を含めて、パフォーマンス改善の為、どの様な対応方法を取るのが適切でしょうか。
　①スペックの低いクライアントのPCでも表示に時間が掛からない。
　②一覧表を最適化し、要件を満たせそうなサードパーティ製品がないか？
　（GrapeCity社のSpread.jsを使えないかと考えています。)

どうしても全項目を並べて表示して値を変更出来る様にしたいという要件があり悩んでおります。

Comment: ページングは試してみましたか？

Comment: 実際に初期表示に30秒かかるサンプルのHTMLを開示すると改善案を出しやすいです。

Comment: 全項目表示という要件の是非は置いとくとして、３０秒のうち、1.サーバでの処理時間 2.ネットワークの転送時間 3.クライアントでの表示時間 はそれぞれどのくらいでしょう？

Answer (score 1):

2万セルの画面で実際に入力を試してみたのでしょうか？ 入力に要する時間はどれぐらいでしょうか？ 入力時間に対して「画面の初期表示に30秒ほど」は無視できない時間でしょうか？ （入力に３時間かかるのなら、初期表示に30秒かかってもたいしたことないのでは？）

また誤りなく入力できますか？ 画面設計を改めるのが先なような気がします。[最適化 - 格言](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%9C%80%E9%81%A9%E5%8C%96_(%E6%83%85%E5%A0%B1%E5%B7%A5%E5%AD%A6)#%E6%A0%BC%E8%A8%80)より

> 「プログラム最適化の第一法則: 最適化するな。プログラム最適化の第二法則（上級者限定）: まだするな。」 - Michael A. Jackson

Comment: 入力に要する時間は0.5秒程度になります。
セル入力ごとにイベントが走り、jsからajaxでDBへの登録まで実施しています。
一応誤りなく入力は出来ている状態です。

Answer (score 0):

質問のコメント欄で提案しましたがページングを試してみてはいかがですか？

ASP.NET MVC でページング (CORE)
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2021/01/30/paging-in-aspnet-core-mvc-application.aspx

質問者さんのアプリのどこがボトルネックなのかわからないので、ピンポイントで改善案は出せませんが、ページングを行えば、(1) 一度に DB から取得するレコード数を減らせる、(2) ASP.NET が html にレンダリングする時のサーバーの負担を減らせる、(3) ブラウザに送信するデータを減らせる、(4) ブラウザの表示にかかる時間を減らせるということで、ある程度効果がありそうな気がします。

Comment: ページングの案ごもっとだと思います。
記述出来ていなかったのですが、実は既にページングは行っていて、元々100列程あるものを制限しています。
行は全て表示したいということで表示件数を減らせないです。

Comment: 情報の後出し小出しは NG です。質問欄を編集してあなたがやったことに追記してください。何に時間がかかっているか計測してボトルネックを明確にしてください。それができるのは質問者さんだけで、その情報なしでここでやり取りしてもお互い時間の無駄になる可能性大ですので。

Comment: 今思ったのですがページングってなんだかわかってますか？　普通は列を制限するのではなくて、一度にページ上に表示する行を制限することを言うのですけど。「行は全て表示し」と言ってますけど 500 行を 1 ページにすべて表示するのが要件？　見ずらいだけと思いますけど？